# How can I create a reusable IAM role for multiple cluster autoscalers in my account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

I have a role with the following trust relationship:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::*:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.*.amazonaws.com/id/*"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.*.amazonaws.com/id/*:sub": "system:serviceaccount:cluster-autoscaler:cluster-autoscaler"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, this does not work:

- wildcards are not permitted in the `Principal` field
- wildcards in the condition key are even more far-fetched

But it should be pretty clear, what I am trying to achieve. The value of the principal is always

```
arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_NO>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.<AWS_REGION>.amazonaws.com/id/<EKS_CLUSTER_ID>
```

and similarly the condition key has a corresponding value of

```
oidc.eks.<AWS_REGION>.amazonaws.com/id/<EKS_CLUSTER_ID>:sub
```

If I input specific values in place of the wildcards, the role works as intended. However, I do not want to grant our CI permission to create roles, so instead I try to create roles that are (in this example) reusable across multiple EKS clusters.

**What I've tried**

I went through a bunch of documentation and found IAM variables and condition operators such as `ARNLike` to be promising, but I didn't manage to find an exhaustive list of available variables and available condition keys given the action (`sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`) and a federated principal.

**How can I create a reusable role, so that I don't have to provision one for every EKS cluster I spin up?**

I'm willing to inadvertently grant an autoscaler from one cluster permissions to scale nodegroups in another, so long as there's no obvious path for further privilege escalation. I'm also willing to consider alternate approaches, perhaps something revolving around tags.

Comment: @Marcin that's quite an unreserved statement. Clearly I can make an assume-role-policy that will accept *any* principal (`"Principal":{"AWS":"*"}`) and drop the condition outright, it'll certainly be reusable, just somewhat overly permissive. The next step, as I imagine, would be to use conditions to limit the scope of this policy, and that is what I'm struggling with. Of course, this might be a case of XY problem and there's a better approach. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It's not related to the question but creating EKS by Terraform can help you automate all the steps and use separated roles for each cluster.

Comment: @FranxiHidro the whole idea, as I've stated in the question body, is *not* to give the gitlab runner which launches terraform the permission to create arbitrary roles.